# map function using foldl or foldr in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function my_map which takes a unary function and a list and returns the list resulting from mapping the function over all elements of the input list.

```
Main> my_map (^3) [1..5]

[1,8,27,64,125]
```

I tried it like this:

```
my_map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
my_map f [] = []
my_map f (x:xs) = foldr (\x xs -> (f x):xs) [] xs
```

But after running above, I get only `[8,27,64,125]`. the first number `1` is not displaying in output.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: just a comment: the higher order functions like `map`, `filter`, `foldx`, ... in a way hide away the *pattern matching* part - therefore you usually won't want to pattern match on the list you are using for those functions (see the good answer below) - also you should accept it (the answer) if it solves your question

Comment: @Carsten Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the (x:xs) pattern in your arguments, but when you apply the fold, you only apply it to the xs part, which means your first element i.e. the one that x represents never gets processed. You need to change it to this:

```
my_map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
my_map f xs = foldr (\y ys -> (f y):ys) [] xs
```

Since you are using `foldr`, you do not need to explicitly handle the empty list case. Moreoever, you do not need to specify the list in (x:xs) format.

Finally, my own preference is to avoid using the same name for function inputs and any helper functions or expressions in the function definition.That is why, I have used `xs` for the input list and `y` and `ys` for the parameters passed to the lambda.

Comment: you should probably rename `x` to `xs` here (as you did with `ys` I guess you just forgot)

Comment: Why not just define `my_map f = foldr ((:) . f) []`?

Comment: If you want to get really pointless then try `flip foldr [] . ((:) .)`.

Comment: @AaditMShah *pointless* ;) ... I think beginners (probably not only those) will have a hard(er) time reading and understanding this

Comment: @Carsten You mean use xs rather than x to inricate its a list?

Answer (score 0):

"shree.pat18" is perfectly right, and also the comments are valuable. I learned a lot from that. Just make it better visible, and to explain the alternatives...

## Answer

```
-- The problem is here ....................... vv
my_map f (x:xs) = foldr (\x xs -> (f x):xs) [] xs
--                                             --
```

The remaining part `xs` is aplied to `foldr`.

To fix just this, apply the whole list. This can be done by placing `xx@` before `(x:xs)`. By that, the whole list is bound to `xx`.

```
--       vvv ........... see here ............... vv
my_map f xx@(x:xs) = foldr (\x xs -> (f x):xs) [] xx
--       ---                                      --
```

## Recommended impovement

Note: `foldr` can already deal with [] as input. Hence, `my_map f [] = []` is not needed. But `foldr` would not be called when you apply `[]` to `my_map`. To get rid of `my_map f [] = []`, you need to remove the pattern matching, because `(x:xs)` matches only to lists with at least one element.

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ my_map (^(3 :: Int)) ([1..5] :: [Integer])

my_map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
my_map f xx = foldr (\x xs -> (f x):xs) [] xx
```

The answer is complete here. The rest below is for pleasure.

## Further reductions

### Simple expression instead of lambda expression

If you want to reduce the lambda expression `(\x xs -> (f x):xs)`, as suggested by "Aadit M Shah"...

`(:)` is equal to `(\x xs -> x:xs)`, because `:` is an operator and its function is `(:)`

`.` can be used to combine the function `f` with `(:)`, hence `(\x xs -> (f x):xs)` is equal to `((:) . f)`

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ my_map (^(3 :: Int)) ([] :: [Integer])

my_map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
my_map f xx = foldr ((:) . f) [] xx
```

### Currying

A function of the form

```
--    v        v
f a b c = .... c
```

can be reduced to

```
--    v        v
f a b   = ....
```

and a function of the form

```
--  v v        v v
f a b c = .... b c
```

can be reduced to

```
--  v v        v v
f a     = ....
```

and so on, by currying.

Hence, `my_map f xx = foldr ((:) . f) [] xx` equals `my_map f = foldr ((:) . f) []`.

### Combination and flip

`flip` flips the first two parameters.

Example, the following functions are equal:

```
f' a b c = (\c' b' a' -> ((a' - b') / c')) b a c

f'' a b c = flip (\c' b' a' -> ((a' - b') / c')) a b c

f''' = flip (\c' b' a' -> ((a' - b') / c'))
```

Hence, the following code works as well.

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ my_map (^(3 :: Int)) ([1..5] :: [Integer])

my_map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
my_map f = flip foldr [] ((:) . f)
```

But we can not get rid of `f` as above, because of the form in the expression `flip foldr [] ((:) . f)`.

If we remove `f` ...

```
`((:) . f)` has type `a -> [a] -> [a]

--     v
`((:) .  )` has type `(a -> a) -> a -> [a] -> [a]`
```

and

```
`flip foldr []` has type `Foldable t => (a1 -> [a2] -> [a2]) -> t a1 -> [a2]`
```

hence

```
f :: a -> a
```

is passed to

```
((:) .  )
```

becomming

```
a -> [a] -> [a]
```

is passed to

```
flip foldr []
```

becomming

```
t a1 -> [a2]
```

Hence,

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ my_map (^(3 :: Int)) ([1..5] :: [Integer])

my_map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
my_map = flip foldr [] . ((:) . )
```

works nicely.